# retrieve a variable from PHP to an Android Class using HttpURLConnection

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

Here is an update of the code I am using it total minus a bunch of non relavent stuff like spinners button intents.   Maybe you can see what I have done wrong better.

my php  I should note, I am new to coding and this is my 1st attempt getting PDO on a download from mysql.  I can upload using PDO.  It looks like it's done right but at this point I can't tell as it's crashing.

Thanks very much for your help.

```
 <?php
  require("conn.php");

 $ID = ["ptID"];

 try{
 $sql = 'SELECT x FROM table WHERE ID = :ID';
 $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute(array('ptID'=> $ID));
 $posts = $stmt->fetchALL();

 $result = mysql_query($conn, $sql);

 if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) > 0)
 {

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$x = $row["x"];

 }

 catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo $sql . "<br>" . $e->getMessage();
 $conn = null;

 ?>
```

this is my activity class ctest

```
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.AdapterView;
 import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.Spinner;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class cervicaltest extends AppCompatActivity implements 
 AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

 //whole bunch of spinners, to collect user input all of which functions. 
 tests prior to adding the code to get data worked find.


 }
 //gets the key to the database for the upload.
 private void useID() {
    SharedPreferences shareID = getSharedPreferences("shareID", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ptID = shareID.getString("ID", "");

}

 public void settest() {
 //bunch of if else statements using the user input.  all of which worked 
 prior to trying to get data.
}

 // both of these were left blank as I never used them.
 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}

//this is the get data class.

 public void getrot() {

gettype ="getcrom";
downloadbackgroundworker Downloadbackgroundworker = new downloadbackgroundworker(this, new downloadbackgroundworker.AsyncResponse() {
    @Override
    public void processfinish(String response) {
        rcervrot = response;
    }
});
    Downloadbackgroundworker.execute(gettype, ptID);
 }

 public void testsaveClick(View view) {

 x = x.getSelectedItem().toString();

    type = "testdb";
    useID();
    getrot();

    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, ptID, x //bunch of variables);


   // Rcervicalticcalcu(); these were marketed out intents that I had used to get data previously but didn't like the            result.  all the code worked, but I kept getting kicked to this activity with the intent and I didn't want to            end up at this activity.  Everything worked good when transfering data as an intent.  So somehow it's getting           the data from the database that is crashing me.  all the code for the intents is marked out.
    //Lcervicalticcalcu();
    settest();
 }
 }
```

Lastly this is the downloadworker class for the getdata.  The upload backgroundworker worked fine prior and I have not changed anything in it.

this is the downloadworker class

```
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.io.OutputStream;
 import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.MalformedURLException;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.net.URLEncoder;


 public class downloadbackgroundworker extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

AlertDialog downloadalert;
Context dlctx;
downloadbackgroundworker (Context dlctx, AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
    this.dlctx = dlctx;
    delegate = asyncResponse;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    downloadalert = new AlertDialog.Builder(dlctx).create();
    downloadalert.setTitle("retrieve Data");

}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params){

    String gettype = params[0];
    String cervrotgeturl = "http://IP/phpfile";
    if(gettype.equals("getcrom"))
    {
        String ID = params[1];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(cervrotgeturl);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("ptID", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ID, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String response ="";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                 response = line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public AsyncResponse delegate = null;

public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processfinish (String response);
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values){
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
    delegate.processfinish(response);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public AsyncResponse delegate=null;

public interface AsyncResponse {
    void processFinish(Boolean output);
}

getBackgroundworker (Context ctx, AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
    this.ctx =ctx;  
    delegate = asyncResponse;
} 

getBackgroundworker(Context ctx)  
{  
    this.ctx =ctx;  
}  

 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        delegate.processFinish(stuff);
//I am passing the boolean variable here. You can pass accordingly

    }
```

Now in the activity in which you want to use the value of stuff variable. You have to implement AsyncResponse  interface and override its method.

Comment: thank you for your reply.  I am getting an error with this in Class A.  It says remove 2nd parameter from method getBackgroundworker   If I click it it removes  AsyncResponse asyncResponse) from      getBackgroundworker (Context ctx, AsyncResponse asyncResponse) {
    this.ctx =ctx;  
    delegate = asyncResponse;

Comment: getBackgroundworker (Content,     AsyncResponce) in getBackgroundworker cannot be applied to (ClassA)   <-- what the mouse says when I put it over the error

Comment: That is due to the difference in constructors. I have updated the code @gtcode.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, been working doubles at work on my odd job while I can.  Usually there never enough hours there.  This didn't work, the 2nd backgroundworker never highlights, it's says never used.  I'm gonna post my whole code below in a little bit.  So you can see it. I'm not sure if it's the background worker class at this point or the activity class that it's coming from or what.  I have played with it a bit and it keeps crashing.  Give me a few minutes I code on a computer with no internet on it, so I have to copy and paste the files on a flash drive then I will post them here.

Comment: ok I edited the code up top so you can see better what I have done.  To use two of the background worker classes, one is always dark saying unused.  I initiated the async in the method as it was the only way to get rid of the error.  In android studio everything in the activity class is checked to green.  In the downloadworkerclass there are a few yellow but no red and all the yellow seem insignificant.

Comment: oh I should mention I tried to implament AsyncResponse into the activity class.  it didn't make any difference, still crashed, i think it wants it into the downloadbackgroundworker call.